# How to add element into each list in a list of list?

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have

```
a={{0,0,0,4},{1,1,1,2}}
```

How to add `0` into each list in the above list of list to obtain the following list of list?

```
b={{0,0,0,4,0},{1,1,1,2,0}}
```

To do this, first, I tried `Insert[pp, Insert[a[[1]], 0, -1], 1]` and obtained `{{0, 0, 0, 4, 0}}` as expected.

Then I add the code into `For`, obtained an error:

`For[i = 0, i < Length[a], i++, Insert[pp, Insert[a[[i]], 0, -1], 1]]`

`Insert::ins: Cannot insert at position {-1} in List`.

Could anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ``Append[0] /@ a``

Comment: `ArrayPad[#, {0, 1}] & /@ a` . This can append/prepend a specified number of 0s and works with matrices. You can also try: `PadRight[#, Length@# + 1, x] & /@ a`. Using insert: `Insert[#, 0, -1] & /@ a`

Comment: It works. Thanks above valuable comments!

Comment: Also `ArrayFlatten[{{a,0}}]`